# String Output Formula to Find Duplicate Transactions Using Date/Amount Value Comparison

Tags: excel

I am trying to look through transactions filtered by 'date' and 'amount', and find/mark duplicates.

Since I was using a filtered view, I tried to keep it simple.

The formula I created looks like:

```
=IF(A4'=A5, IF(D4'=D5, 'Duplicate'), 'Not ')

** Doesn't like my use of '='

** Formula Syntax Error
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @pnuts I was trying to appease the excel error that was stuck on my use of (=).  The tactic was recommended by a co-worker.

Comment: @pnuts correct. However, It could be a problem with my usage of _IF_ .

Comment: @pnuts It doesn't appear I can. I also tried wrapping the cell in VALUE or SUM, it still seems to have issues with my use of '='. I know in js '=' denotes setting a something equal to a value (variable definition), and '===' denotes a comparison. I wonder if that might be the issue.

Comment: ... and stop listening to that co-worker.

Comment: @Jeeped agreed sir. He is a Ruby Developer, so I can't blame him too much if you can't help me in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=if(And(A4=A5,D4=D5),"Duplicate","Not")
```

Answer (score 0):

### FIXED:

```
=IF(A4=A5, IF(D4=D5, "Duplicate"), "Not ")
```

**The error was coming from using ' instead of " after-all.**

> Why single (not double) inverted commas around the text strings and
> why the other two single inverted commas?
>
> –  @pnuts